# Unable to install fastquant in new virtualenv conda

Tags: python, pandas, package, anaconda, conda

In base environment I have already installed fastquant package

but after creating and activating new conda environment I am not able to install the fastquant package.

I already have pandas 1.5.2

but when I install fastquant it is trying to install pandas 1.1.5 as it is a dependency

```
Collecting fastquant
  Using cached fastquant-0.1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.9 MB)
Collecting oauthlib>=3.1.0
  Using cached oauthlib-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (151 kB)
Collecting chardet>=3.0.4
  Using cached chardet-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (199 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.28.1 in c:\users\11832\anaconda3\envs\fbprophetenv\lib\site-packages (from fastquant) (4.64.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.13.0 in c:\users\11832\anaconda3\envs\fbprophetenv\lib\site-packages (from fastquant) (1.16.0)
Collecting tweepy>=3.8.0
  Using cached tweepy-4.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.9.5 in c:\users\11832\anaconda3\envs\fbprophetenv\lib\site-packages (from fastquant) (2.3.2.post1)
Collecting black>=19.10b0
  Using cached black-23.1a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting nltk>=3.5
  Using cached nltk-3.8-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.25.7 in c:\users\11832\anaconda3\envs\fbprophetenv\lib\site-packages (from fastquant) (1.26.13)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2019.11.28 in c:\users\11832\anaconda3\envs\fbprophetenv\lib\site-packages (from fastquant) (2022.12.7)
Collecting pandas==1.1.5
  Using cached pandas-1.1.5.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... \
```

but is it failing after this with following error:

```
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pandas\_libs\tslibs
      copying pandas\_libs\tslibs\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pandas\_libs\tslibs
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pandas\_libs\window
      copying pandas\_libs\window\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pandas\_libs\window
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pandas\io\formats\templates
      copying pandas\io\formats\templates\html.tpl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pandas\io\formats\templates
      UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pandas/_version.py
      set build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pandas/_version.py to '1.1.5'
      running build_ext
      building 'pandas._libs.algos' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyPI package has the version of pandas pinned to 1.1.5, it is probably a mistake.  The current version of `python/requirements.txt` in the github repo has it as `pandas >= 1.1.5`.

You can raise an issue on the github repo to report it.  In the mean time, you can install Pandas 1.1.5 using conda before you install fastquant.

```
conda install pandas==1.1.5
```